# How to configure the ruby edition on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using MAC to learn RoR. The default Ruby in system is 2.0.0, and I installed the newest Ruby 2.2.1(not in System). However, when I run rails server, it uses ruby 2.0.0. How can I configure rails to make it use newer Ruby?

When I run "ruby -v" in terminal, the version is 2.2.1

Comment: You can add ruby version in gemfile

Comment: try with `rvm install ruby 2.2.1`, after that run `rvm list` to see all version installed, and then run `rvm use 2.2.1` to use ruby 2.2.1

Comment: @anonymousxxx thx, I find .rvm I can only find 2.0.0 in rvm. So I have no idea where is my ruby 2.2.1. Anyway, I am installing ruby 2.2.3 now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I advise you to install a Ruby version manager app. I have been using [RVM](https://rvm.io/) for a while.

With RVM you can have multiple versions of Ruby installed and select witch one is to be used by default.

Rails is a Gem that would be installed into each of the Ruby packages in separated, or you can have RVM to do the gem management for you as well.

Give it a try and let us know if you need more help.

Comment: thx, I have rvm, and I am reading the doc. I can only find 2.0.0 in rvm, thats strange.

Comment: installing ruby 2.2.3 now.

Comment: I was about to ask you to verify the installed ones with `rvm list`, let me know when it finishes

Comment: rvm rubies

 * ruby-2.0.0-p598 [ x86_64 ]
=> ruby-2.2.3 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

Comment: I forgot to tell you to set the default version...  use: `rvm --default use 2.2.3`

Comment: emm, installing rails now, may I do it later?

Comment: before installing rails, verify the active ruby with a `ruby -v` if it is already 2.2.3 you are good to go

Comment: getting crazy, when I typed ruby -v first time, it told 2.2.3, but now is 2.2.1. dunno why, theres no 2.2.1 in rvm.

Comment: My advise is that you remove all ruby's installed in your system, remove RVM as well and start again with a "clean" setup...

Answer (score 1):

In your `Gemfile` add ruby version you wanted to use. ie

```
ruby "2.2.1"
```

If you are using `rvm` then

```
>$ rvm install 2.2.1
>$ cd <app root dir>
>$ rvm install 2.2.1
>$ cd 
>$ cd <app root dir>
```

Comment: So I need to do this every time I build new project?

Comment: you will have to specify once in `Gemfile`, it will be available. if you want to move to latest version again you will have to change the `Gemfile` with latest ruby version.

Comment: I did, but it tells that I do not have 2.2.1, in .rvm I can only see 2.0.0